# Invalid DataSpec parameters playing encrypted video with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer

I'm trying to play AES/GCM/NoPadding encrypted files via ExoPlayer. As the code is rather large I've made it available in a Github Gist. The application allows users to watch video stream which they can save for saving bandwidth. As the content is proprietary the saved videos are encrypted to protect intellectual rights.

I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/Parsoa/e5c2895d59a2fbd32efcdf1156975d41) (Github Gist) DataSource implementation based on [this](http://upshots.org/android/android-play-encrypted-video-in-exoplayer) tutorial. On some devices (with android versions ranging from 4.1.1 to 5.1.1) the `DataSpec.position` returns numbers far beyond the size of the actual file which causes the device to get stuck in the `forceSkip` method. 
Removing the forceSkip call also doesn't seem to work as the device would then get stuck in an endless cycle of `open` and `read` calls.

My encryption logic is correct as trying to decrypt the entire file first and saving it to a temporary file and then playing from that works fine on all those devices. But this approach isn't feasible as the decryption would take a long time (minutes) for the video sizes I'm dealing with (20-30mb).

As I have no control over how the player is initializing the `DataSpec` and calling the `DataSource` methods I'm beginning to suspect this might be a platform bug. Any help in understanding or fixing the problem is appreciated.

Comment: whats wrong with [this](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/crypto/AesCipherDataSource.html)?

Comment: @pskink This doesn't support GCM mode. The constructor only accepts a secret key and no IV.

Comment: ok so whats the problem with adding whatever you want to its sources?

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm about to do. The problem is I can't find a clean sample for playing local files with ExoPlayer. Looks like everyone just needs to stream HLS ... . My local MediaSource might eventually be the real problem.

Comment: use [this](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/FileDataSource.html) as `upstream` parameter for example

Comment: or [this](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultDataSource.html)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out ! you saved me :)

Comment: sure, no problem

Comment: And what was the solution? Please add it as the answer.

Comment: @DarthPaghius did you ever work this out? I seem to be having a similar issue using AES/GCM/NoPadding